# Worried about threading in python on apache server

Tags: python, multithreading, apache

I don't need the threads to be aware of each other. They just need to preform a task that shouldn't take more than two or three seconds tops. What can I do to guarantee that the tread will not be killed before the task is completed. Also, I need to use the occasionally timer thread. The timer is only for a minute but I'm nervous about that being too long for apache.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't start these threads in the background?  Why do they need to be part of the webserver?  I would suggest that you write some scripts that either sit idle in the background all the time, or are called periodically by a `cron` job.  The python scripts could lookup info in the database or even use a file to indicate what it needs to do, run, then exit.